# ImportError: No module named 'Cython' when installing Cython on mac for darkflow

Tags: python, macos, cython, cythonize, darkflow

I'm trying to install darkflow on my mac and I've already downloaded cython extensions.

I'm trying to use this command on terminal:

```
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    from Cython.Build import cythonize
ImportError: No module named 'Cython'
```

Any ideas how to fix this error?

Comment: Did you use pip install Cython?

Answer (score 4):

Try using

> pip install cython

OR

You can download the latest Cython release from http://cython.org. Unpack the tarball or zip file, enter the directory, and then run:

python setup.py install

Hope it works!

Comment: or you need 'change 'python' to 'python3' in makefile